# Actionscript 3.0 Cut and Paste or Delete an object

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, copy-paste, cut

I have some folders, let's say A,B,c in application directory. There is also a file D in this directory too. What I want is copying all folders into application storage directory without copying D. OR after copying all files and folders, I want to delete D. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading the documentation for [`File`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html).

You can do it one of two ways:

1. Do each directory one by one. You would move `File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath( "A" )` using `moveTo( File.applicationStorageDirectory )` (I believe. You may need to resolve the actual directory name as well. Test for that). You then use `deleteDirectory` on each directory (you do not want to delete your applicationDirectory, obviously).
2. Move the entire `File.applicationDirectory` to `File.applicationStorageDirectory` using the above moveTo method. I am unsure what else is present in that applicationDirectory, however, so you may move and delete things you do not want to. For that reason, I would suggest method 1

Comment: Thank you a lot. It wasn't allowed to move folders from applicationDirectory, instead I copied them and deleteDirectory and deleteFile worked for me :)

Comment: Yeah, I wondered if there would be issues like that. applicationDirectory, especially on mobile devices, isn't meant to be used as a storage spot. You should always use applicationStorageDirectory. Glad I could lead you in the right direction at the very least